# Ошибка при добавлении строчки в sqlite3 python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Имеется вот такой код:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

big = 'other'
string = 'ok'

con = sqlite3.connect('aa.db')
cur = con.cursor()  

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, big, 'default', '', 'no', string, '0')")

con.commit()
con.close()
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: big
```

Ошибка возникает по всей видимости из за переменных 'big' и 'string'.

Можно как то выполнить добавления строчки в базу *sqlite3* с использованием этих переменных?

Comment: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, ?, 'default', '', 'no', ?, '0')", (big, string))`

Answer (score 2):

Для создания запросов к базе данных в целях безопасности всегда рекомендуется использовать `placeholder`. В модуле `sqlite3` для этого в текст запроса вместо переменных проставляются символы знака вопроса (`?`) либо используются `named placeholder`, а в метод `execute` вторым параметром передаётся список подставляемых переменных для первого случая, либо словарь - для второго.

Пример с использованием знака вопроса:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, ?, 'default', '', 'no', ?, '0')", (big, string))
```

Пример с использованием `named placeholders`

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, :big, 'default', '', 'no', :string, '0')", {"big": big, "string": string})
```

---

**Дополнено с комментария @jfs**

Если во втором случае названия переменных совпадают с названиями `named placeholder`, то в метод `execute` вторым параметром можно передать словарь `vars`

```
big = 'other'
string = 'ok'
cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, :big, 'default', '', 'no', :string, '0')", vars())
```

Comment: Чтобы руками словарь не писать, то можно просто `vars()` передать в примере с именованными параметрами.

Comment: Спасибо все получилось

Answer (score 0):

У вас big и string получаются как просто слова внутри строки запроса. Чтобы их значения подставлялись в запрос можно использовать format.

Вместо той строки, где выполняется запрос, поставьте эти две строки:

```
query = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, {}, 'default', '', 'no', {}, '0')".format(big, string)
cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: `no such column: other`

Comment: Так ведь в кавычках же надо: `VALUES (NULL, '{}', 'default', '', 'no', '{}', '0')`

Comment: @aleks.andr `big = "ot'her"` и всё снова грустно :)

Comment: не используйте строковое форматирование для создания sql query. [Передайте лучше как параметры.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628435/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2sqlite3-python3#comment881613_628435)

Comment: Спасибо все получилось